# lvalue required as left operand assignment when

Tags: c++

I'm using a insertSort method on my array based list, and to sort the list I'm using my getRanking that is and int variable 
but it is giving me "lvalue required as left operand"

```
 void bookList::insertionSort(){
 int j,temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++){
        j = i;

        while (j > 0 && myBooks[j].getBookranking() < myBooks[j-1].getBookranking()){
              temp = myBooks[j].getBookranking();
              myBooks[j].getBookranking() = myBooks[j-1].getBookranking();
              myBooks[j-1].getBookranking() = temp;
              j--;
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: `myBooks[j].getBookranking() = myBooks[j-1].getBookranking();` How will this work.You are assigning  to something that is being returned from a function.

Comment: and how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you have a `setBookranking()` method?If not, this is good time to make it.

Comment: Yes i already have it

Comment: something like `myBooks[j].setBookranking(myBooks[j-1].getBookranking())`

Comment: thanks dude your the best

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 3):

```
myBooks[j].getBookranking()
```

is presumably a function that returns a value, e.g.

```
int getBookranking() { ... }
```

when you return by value like this, you return a temporary or *rvalue*. Thus

```
getBookranking() = getBookranking()
```

makes no sense - all it does is overwrite one temporary with another and then discards them.

You will need something like a `setBookranking` function:

```
myBooks[j].setBookranking(myBooks[j-1].getBookranking());
myBooks[j-1].setBookranking(temp);
```